# Prove if $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of X, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $X^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Question I'm trying to solve is in the title.

My work:

If $Xv = \lambda v$ for vector v, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of X.

We have $Xv = \lambda v$, multiplying both sides of the equation by $X^T$ yields:

$X^TXv =X^T \lambda v$

and

$X^TX \implies I$

Therefore, $Iv =X^T \lambda v$, which is

$v =X^T \lambda v$

which gives me

$\lambda^{-1}v =X^Tv$

but this implies that $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $X^T$, not $\lambda$.

Did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: Why do you have $X^TX = I$ ?

Comment: Oh that's not an identity of transpose matrices... I mixed it up with inverse matrices.

Comment: can you share the correct proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\chi_A$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$. The eigen values of A are the roots of $\chi_A$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial)

As $$\chi_X = \chi_{X^T}$$ so we have the result.

Comment: +1. It's probably worth justifying this a little more closely. $\chi_{A} = \text{det}(A - \lambda I) = \text{det}( (A - \lambda I)^T) = \text{det}(A^{T} - \lambda I) = \chi_{A^{T}}$. The second equality follows from the fact that the determinant is invariant under transposition. The last equality follows from the fact that $I$ is symmetric, so $I^{T} = I$.